# Talend ETL - tFTPGet component 'local directory' issue where i am unable to load the files on the ETL server

Tags: ftp, talend

I am using FTP to pull a file from a remote server, which I then want to copy to the local talend server for use in other jobs and processes.

I have used a tFTPConnection to tFTPFileList to tFTPGet routine, and the GET works absolutely fine if I use a directory to my local machine. i.e. Local Directory = `"C:/"`

But, as I say, I want the GET to put the file onto the talend server so that the job can be run out of hours when my machine isn't switched on. So I change the Local Directory to something like: `"/var/etl/input/PROD/REPORTING/"` and for some reason the file no longer copies across.
Other than the local directory option in the tFTPGet, I am not changing any other settings.

Does anyone know why I am encountering this issue? Or if this is even supported by Talend?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On doing some research and speaking to some contacts in Talend support, it appears the issue is that I was attempting to run the job from my local workstation.

As the files need to be sent a directory local to the server itself, it needs to be run through the Talend Administration Centre.